# What is the name of the flower in the picture?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]
I bought this flower 2 days ago. But I don't know the name of this flower. What is the name of this flower? And why is it not blooming?

Comment: This  is not the question you originally posted, which is why the answer below doesn't fit. Please post a new question separately, including a photograph.

Comment: @trina Don't change a question completely after someone has taken the time and effort to answer the original. As Bamboo says, post a new one, possibly with a link back to this one for context, if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Canna variety, and it **is** blooming - the flowers just haven't opened out fully yet. Give it time, they will.